Twilio 21612 - Message cannot be sent with the current combination of 'To' and/or 'From' parameters
I have some problems using twilio to test some sms sending from a twilio number to my phyical phone.
I have purchased a US number (+1) and trying to send to a Greek number (+30). The 'To' number is added as a verified caller id.
I get this error

Message cannot be sent with the current combination of 'To'
(+3069XXXXXXXX) and/or 'From' (+1219327XXXX) parameters

Also there are now Greek numbers to buy if this was the issue.
I know that in other implementations we were using again US numbers as senders.
Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Do you have Geo-location enabled for Greece?

Yes, also checked that. Both US and Greece checkboxes are checked.

When you get that error message, it means the numbers are not compliant. Sorry. Have you tried using a number from another EU member instead?

@IObert thank you for the answer. I am trying to receive a message in a physical personal number so I have only tested with this one. For example, the virtual phone is working when I am using two +1 numbers. The thing is that we used to use Twilio in other instances from (+1) to (+30) which seems to not be working currently.

If it's just for dev purposes, you can buy two +30 numbers and use one with the dev phone.
